# openGL rectangle rendering triangle instead?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

So i'm trying to render a rectangle in openGL using index buffers however instead i'm getting a triangle with one vertex at the origin (even though no vertex in my rectangle is suppsoed to go at the origin).

[image: Screenshot of the triangle in wireframe mode]

```
void Renderer::drawRect(int x,int y,int width, int height)
{   

    //(Ignoring method arguments for debugging)
    float vertices[12] = {200.f, 300.f, 0.f,
                          200.f, 100.f, 0.f,
                          600.f, 100.f, 0.f,
                          600.f, 300.f, 0.f};

    unsigned int indices[6] = {0,1,3,1,2,3};

    glBindVertexArray(this->flat_shape_VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,this->element_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(indices),indices,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,this->render_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices),vertices,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glUseProgram(this->shader_program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(this->model_view_projection_uniform,1,GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(this->model_view_projection_mat));
    glUniform3f(this->color_uniform,(float) this->color.r,(float)this->color.g,(float)this->color.b);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,nullptr);

}
```

My projection matrix is working fine I can still render a triangle at the correct screen coords. I suspect maybe I did index buffering wrong? Transformation matrices also work fine, atleast on my triangles.

Edit:

The VAO's attributes are set up in the class constructor with `glVertexAttribPointer();`

Edit 2:
I disabled shaders completely and [something interesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD794.png) happened.

[image: something interesting]

Here is the shader source code:
(vertex shader)

```
    #version 330 core
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
    uniform mat4 mvp;
    uniform vec3 aColor;
    out vec3 color;
    void main()
    {
       gl_Position = mvp * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
       color = aColor;

    }
```

(fragment shader)

```
    #version 330 core
    in vec3 color;
    out vec4 FragColor;
    void main()
    {
       FragColor = vec4(color,1.0f);
    }
```

My projection matrix shouldn't work with shaders disabled yet I still see a triangle rendering on the screen..??

Comment: What are the arguments of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)? What is the _stride_ argument? It should be 0 or 12 (`3*sizeof(float)`) but it seems to be 24.

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are right, the stride was set to  6*sizeof(float)  because I had recently removed the color attrib from the vertices and forgot to change it back to 3*sizeof(float). That did fix the issue, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the stride argument of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)? *stride* specifies the byte offset between consecutive generic vertex attributes. In your case it should be 0 or 12 (`3*sizeof(float)`) but if you look at your images it seems to be 24 because the triangle has the 1st (200, 300) and 3rd (600, 100) vertices and one more vertex with the coordinate (0, 0).

<s>`glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), nullptr);`</s>

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), nullptr);
```